# Two 15A GFCI Breakers Tripping Overnight

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, gfci

Last night while coming home I found that a breaker had tripped. Looked around and didn't see issues so I flipped it back on. We'll call this GFCI breaker #1. Later the breaker tripped again but I didn't realize it was a different one let's call it #2. I didn't realize this is because one bedroom has a wall on circuit #1 and the rest of the bedroom on #2. I was trying to find a possible issue for it such as a bad device, appliance, etc. Couldn't so again I flipped it back on. Later that night again breaker #2 trips. About an hour later breaker #1 trips. I left them off and went to sleep :)

What could cause 2 GFCI breakers to trip? They are completely 2 different circuits. This is the first this has happened. These are the only GFCI breakers in the house. I'm not sure why they were added since both circuits are for bedrooms. None of the bedrooms have GFCI outlets.

UPDATE 10/24 - So in the last 2 days I've had no issues. The same devices were plugged in.

Updated with image of the two breakers.

[image]

Comment: Would unplug everything that is plugged into those two circuits, should isolate the problem is a device or the circuit.  GFCI breakers trip for one of two reasons, an overload(like simple breakers) or a minor but dangerous ground fault(bad insulation, moisture/water on connections).

Comment: Are you sure they're GFCIs? Can you post photos of the breakers in question? (I suspect they're actually AFCIs, given what they serve)

Comment: Check to make sure there aren't any outdoor outlets, landscape lights through the walls to the outside.

Comment: Some models are also transient sensitive. I have them once in a while trip if the power blinks or lightning strikes close. It is never the same one each time. They are all located externally from the main panels.

Comment: When you say the breaker tripped. Is it a GFCI trip or an overcurrent trip? Also look at ThreePhaseEel's comment. It's unusual for GFCI's to be serving bedroom receptacles.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel added an image of the breakers. They say "Circuit Breaker and GFCI".

Comment: @RetiredMasterElectrician added an image of the breakers. They say "Circuit Breaker and GFCI". Sorry not sure how I would tell between a GFCI trip and an overcurrent trip. Can you explain? The breaker was "tripped" and was in the middle. I shut it completely off and then reengaged it without an issue.

Comment: @Gil this is what I'm leaning towards. Because it doesn't make sense for both to go out around the same time for different circuits. There is no new construction being done, no new appliances/devices, and nothing different than the previous day.

Comment: @null -- is the GND FAULT light on the breakers on when you find them tripped?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I saw one flicker, but no they were not on.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately your Siemens GFCI breaker does not have an led that indicates which type of trip you have. The newer AFCI/GFCI combo's do.

Assuming that you tripping is not an overload, and the two circuits are on separate poles. My best guess would be that they are sharing a neutral somewhere downstream and at some random time either or both breakers are sensing a neutral imbalance and tripping out.

Also assuming that the shared neutral is between the breakers and the first device on both circuits. You can replace the GFCI breakers with standard breakers and provide a GFCI device at the first device of each circuit. Thus giving you the same protection you have only in two locations rather than one.

If the neutrals are intertwined between the both circuits and cannot be separated. Then you still need too replace both breakers and replace devices that the NEC requires to be on GFCI's with GFCI devices.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It looks like the QPF2 type breakers *do* have the trip indicator LED functionality

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that hardly is given much consideration.
Breaker switches also get old like anything else in life.

To check for this to be in case.  Swap it with another 15A breaker switch and see what happens.
This way you know if it is the breaker switch or not.

Oh I should edit to add another thing.
It doesn't matter if another 15A breaker switch is not GFCI.  Swap them, it won't hurt a thing.

It is a simple thing to rule out, in case old age be the cause.  You know like me. :-)

Take good care.